# Overleaf ftp access?

Tags: overleaf

I have read [on this website](https://medium.com/thoughts-philosophy-writing/how-to-use-overleaf-to-write-your-papers-part-i-basic-minimalist-setup-6599268c095f) that I can access overleaf via FTP, but it doesn't say how. Can anyone help me with that? Other protocolls are also fine, I just want to mount it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You could write to support@overleaf.com, they usually reply very quickly.

Comment: (I'm a support person at Overleaf.) Hi @ASDArray, I believe you contacted us at support, but I got a non-deliverable notice when trying to reply. We do not support FTP, but we do offer git protocol support, which may be an option for you. Direct git access is available in Overleaf v1. And Overleaf v2 has Github integration at the moment, but we're working on direct git access in v2 and aim to have it ready by the time Overleaf v1 is deprecated. Probably not exactly what you're after, but it might work for you.

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks for the response! I will try to do it with dropbox then, as we are using v2. Anyways, it's weird that you couldn't reply. I recently changed my email, and was able to confirm it.